# Extjs 3.4 How to get the inner html of a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

So in my application I have a panel that contains the legend for other displayed panels. I have been working on an export that exports the other grids to excel. I want to export the panel with the legend onto the bottom of each page.

My problem is very basic. I am trying to get the legend from within the panel and send it to my export plugin.

I am doing this:

```
var legendPanel = Ext.getCmp('simpleCompareListPanel');
```

and then I am trying to use that object to get the inner html / text so i can add it to my export.

I have tried `legendPanel.el.dom.innerHtml` but i get undefined. When looking at my object this would seem to be where the inner html is.

Any help?

Comment: Did you examine the `legendPanel` using firebug/developer tools?

Comment: Evan Trimboli - That is correct!! Wow, I can't believe I didn't see my incorrect capitalization. Shows you I have been working on this too long. Thanks! (p.s. if you put that as an answer i will mark it as such)

Comment: However, I have another minor issue. Since I am exporting to excel I would rather have the plain text instead of the html markup. When looking in my developer tools it would seem that would be in `innerText` but when i log that to the console it only gives me up to the first line break.

Comment: FYI I figured out that I was grabbing the text before the panel had finished rendering. Thanks again